# Magento 2.3 reverts the DB update on static files deployment

Tags: magento2

Few customers of mine are complaining that every time they deploy the static files on Magento 2.3, the size of the column simple_action in the salesrule table goes back to the original value 32. (After being updated by a DB script of the extension to 255).

Has somebody encountered a similar issue? Since I didn't see that myself and I only rely on their words - maybe there is some other deployment process (a compilation?) that can cause it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the DB was reverting the column size each time the customer ran php bin/magento setup:upgrade.

I figured that it happens because in Magento 2.3 schema modifications has to be done in db_schema.xml. I defined the column modification in the db_schema.xml and it fixed the issue.